# Adding links to icons

Tags: html, css

I made a site for myself for the first time and added icons to share my social media pages, I don't know how to add links to icons. I would be glad if you could help.

Html:

```
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
```

Comment: Change `<i>` to `<a href="http://where-to-go.com">`?

Comment: you can add <a> tag begging of <i> tag like that: <a href="where to go"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>  take look at this link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: Try using [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag

Comment: I would suggest working through some basic HTML tutorials, one of the many free beginner courses you can find online will save you a lot of time in the long run. (Feel free to ask here if you get stuck, but try to do a bit of research yourself first)

Answer (score 2):

Font awesome does not care if icons are set in `<i>` tags, use `<a>` instead of `<i>`

```
<a href="FB Link" class="fab fa-facebook"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this using html  tag,

```
<a href="Your facebook link"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
```